# what will be my gateway in multiple VPN Connections?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, internet-connection

as we know we can connect multiple VPNs in same time and my question is about what will be our gateway in this situation or how can we determine what will be our gateway?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gets set depends on your VPN settings.  But you can change the settings of your VPN profiles.  Set your default gateway to which ever network you want to use for all traffic that you haven't directed to other networks with static routes.

If for some silly reason, you have multiple networks/vpn profiles trying to set a default gateway, then the computer will look at the metric.  The lowest metric wins.